# Is there a way to check if checkboxes in Google Forms are checked through Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm attempting to create a Google Script that allows branching logic, however I don't see in the Google App Script documentation a method that verifies if a checkbox is marked as true or false.

Is there a way to confirm in a script, if an option is selected or not before submitting the whole Google Form?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent submitting the form depending on the checkbox value, you can make the selection required, or you can validate the response.
To implement the branching logic in the forms, you must use the multiple choice control.
With Apps script you have much more validation options, but only after the form has been submitted.

[image]
[image]